# ASP NET Core: Aliases in docker-compose don't appear in /etc/hosts

Tags: asp.net, docker, docker-compose

I have a Docker supported ASP NET Core app.

The docker-compose file looks like this:

```
version: '3'

services:
  test:
    image: test
    build:
      context: ./Test
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    networks:
      test_nw:
        aliases: 
          - test_alias

  oracledb:
    image: sath89/oracle-12c
    ports: 
      - "1521:1521"
    networks:
      test_nw:
        aliases: 
          - oracledb_alias

networks:
  test_nw:
```

But after starting the app I looked in the container of the ASP.NET Core app (do`cker exec -it ... bash`) and checked the `/etc/hosts` file but the respective alias of the DB `oracledb_alias` does not appear in it. So the app does not find the DB when using `oracledb_alias` as host name in the connection string.

What did I do wrong? How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did nothing wrong. Docker's earlier versions used to use `/etc/hosts` for resolving hostname and links. Now docker uses a internal DNS server for this.

So you don't get to see any information as such. Then only thing you can do is use a command and test if you can reach resolve the name or not

```
$ dig oracledb_alias
$ ping oracledb_alias
$ telnet oracledb_alias 1521
```

See the below link for more details

https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/configure-dns/

Comment: I see. When I check the network via docker inspect I can see the right ip addresses under "Containers": But the names looks wrong. It says "dockercompose9881130304305912251_oracledb_1". But I assume the name is "oracledb".

Comment: That is the name of the container. The container insider the container network can still be resolved using `oracledb`. The container name on the host machine has to be unique, so docker-compose mixes folder name, service name and instance number

Comment: Ok. Ping within the container to the other container works.